# Decomposing a vector to two vectors

Tags: vectors, computational-geometry

There is a statement by professor in class that every vector $\vec p$ could be decomposed to whatever other two vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ for which ${\vec u \times \vec v \neq 0}$. So they are not collinear.

[image]

The decomposition is stated it represents: $$\vec p = \frac{(\vec p \times \vec v)\vec u +(\vec u \times \vec p)\vec v}{\vec u \times \vec v}$$
Which is stated to come from the equation $$\vec p = k \vec u+l\vec v$$ (seems to me the parallelogram law) by doing cross product on both sides with ${\times \vec v}$ and ${\vec u \times }$, where `k` and `l` are constants.

What I happened to get to is the following equations:
$$\vec p \times \vec v = (k \vec u+l\vec v) \times \vec v=k(\vec u \times \vec v)+l(\vec v \times \vec v)=k(\vec u \times \vec v)+0$$

$$\vec u \times \vec p = \vec u\times(k \vec u+l\vec v)  =k(\vec u \times \vec u)+l(\vec u \times \vec v)=l(\vec u \times \vec v)+0$$

It is added that if $\vec v$ is the perpendicular of $\vec u$, then the equation will be $$\vec p=( \hat u \cdot \vec p )\hat u + ( \hat u \times \vec p )\hat v$$, which comes from the properties of the vector operations.

I don't understand how does it come from the equation and where do the constants go and why do they appear in the first place?
Would appreciate the help and resources to relevant additional information.

Comment: @user Could you please elaborate on your comment

Comment: @user The word in my language is not easily translated, but it should give twice the area of a triangle and it should show us how these points are oriented, it is also knows as the cross product, isn't it?

Comment: I'm trying to understand better your question.

Comment: @user Feel free to ask me on what should I elaborate on

Comment: The first part now is clear! What is the part is not clear to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ not collinear they are a basis therefore for some $k$ and $l$ we have

$$\vec p = k \vec u+l\vec v$$

then we are stating that

$$\vec p = \frac{(\vec p \times \vec v)\vec u +(\vec u \times \vec p)\vec v}{\vec u \times \vec v}$$

since

$$\vec p \times \vec v = (k \vec u+l\vec v) \times \vec v=k(\vec u \times \vec v)+l(\vec v \times \vec v)=k(\vec u \times \vec v)+\vec 0=k(\vec u \times \vec v)$$

$$\vec u \times \vec p = \vec u\times(k \vec u+l\vec v)  =k(\vec u \times \vec u)+l(\vec u \times \vec v)=\vec 0+l(\vec u \times \vec v)=l(\vec u \times \vec v)$$

and then

$$\require{cancel}
\vec p = \frac{(\vec p \times \vec v)\vec u +(\vec u \times \vec p)\vec v}{\vec u \times \vec v}=\frac{k\cancel{(\vec u \times \vec v)}\vec u+l\cancel{(\vec u \times \vec v)}\vec v}{\cancel{\vec u \times \vec v}}=k \vec u+l\vec v$$

and in this way the identity works.

For the final part, it is stated is that when $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are perpendicular we can also refer to

$$\vec p=( \hat u \cdot \vec p )\hat u + ( \hat u \times \vec p )\hat v$$

with

$$\hat u \cdot \vec p =\hat u \cdot ( k \vec u+l\vec v)=k|u|+0=k|u|$$

$$\hat u \times \vec p =\hat u \times ( k \vec u+l\vec v)=0+l|v|=l|v|$$

and therefore

$$\vec p=( \hat u \cdot \vec p )\hat u + ( \hat u \times \vec p )\hat v=$$

$$=k|u|\hat u+l|v|\hat v=k\vec u + l \vec v$$

Comment: Wow. Now I get every aspect of it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure for the last part, can you check the latter formula was given in class?

Comment: The only thing that was given in class was what `p` was equal to and from where he got it. "It is trivial"

Comment: @vikAy Ok now all is clear and fine! You can try to edit your question using the text I've used here or I can do it if it is fine for you.

Comment: Edited it by myself, don't bother. Thank you again.

Comment: Very nice! Now it is really better, nice work.